# Gem conflict with refinerycms core and custom engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

First, I apologize ahead of time for any confusion / lack of clarity, this is my first stackoverflow post.

I built a custom engine for my refinery app with the typical:

```
rails generate refinery:engine web_users first_name:string last_name:string...
```

Running this puts a gem in the gemfile like so:

```
gem 'refinerycms-web_users', :path => 'vendor/extensions'
```

However, I also have 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', '~> 1.0.0' in my gemfile for foundation as my front-end framework (specifically for mobile menu navigation).

When running bundle update I get the following error:

```
refinerycms (~> 2.1.2) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-core (= 2.1.2) ruby

refinerycms-web_users (>= 0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-core (2.0.10)
```

Is there either a solution for downgrading acts-as-index to play nice with refinerycms-core (2.0.10) or to bump up the dependency of a custom engine to refinerycms 2.1.2?

Thanks errrrybody!

Sorry, realize I didn't put the error with acts-as-indexed with refinerycms core 2.1.0:

```
refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (~> 1.0.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-core (~> 2.1.0) ruby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade your extension to depend on `refinerycms-core ~> 2.1.0` which you can do by opening (something like) `vendor/extensions/refinerycms-web_users/refinerycms-web_users.gemspec` and specifying the updated dependency version in place of what is already specified.  You'll then want to ensure that it works properly with the updated version of `refinerycms-core`.

Comment: That worked perfectly and makes perfect sense. Thanks so much for the quick reply!